# $G$ is a group with order $mn$ where $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Then for any $g$ there are $x$ and $y$ such that $xy=g=yx$ and $x^m=1=y^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $g$ be an element of a group $G$, and suppose that $|G|=mn$ where $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Prove that there are unique elements $x$ and $y$ of $G$ such that $xy=g=yx$ and $x^m=1=y^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose such $x,y $ exist. Then $g=xy = (xy)^1$.

$m, n $ are coprime so according to  Bezout's identity there are integers $a,b $ such that $am+bn=1$.

Replacing the $1$ in the previous equality, $g=(xy)^{am+bn} $.

Given that $x,y $ commute and $x^m=y^n=1$, we get $g=x^{bn}y^{am} $.

We get the two equations $g=xy $ and $g=x^{bn}y^{am} $.

So $y = x^{-1}g $ and substituting $y $ in the second equality, $g = x^{bn}(x^{-1}g)^{am} = x^{bn}g^{am} $, so $x^{bn} = g^{1-am}$.

Using $am+bn=1$ twice, we get $x=g^{bn}$. This gives $y=g^{am} $.

You can verify that $x=g^{bn}, y=g^{am} $ verify your hypothesis, hence the existence.

Now, for uniqueness, I'll let you prove that $a $ is unique mod $n $ and $b $ is unique mod  $m $ and why this is enough to assert uniqueness.
**Hint**: for the first part, try solving $tm+un =1$ for integers $t, u $, knowing that $am+bn=1$.

Comment: Thanks! That's quite straightforward

Comment: I've asked two questions tonight and both of them were easily answered. Maybe that's because i haven't get in touch with abstract algebra for a year. I think i need some time to restore.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't say that it was easy. It took me some time and several tentatives before getting something interesting. It's not hard, but it's not easy either.

Comment: Can you point out to me where you prove that such $x$ and $y$ exists and where it is given that $x$ and $y$ commute and $x^m=y^n=1$?

Comment: @user170039 : first, I assumed such x,y exist. I prove then that, assuming existence, necessarily $x=g^{bn}, y= g^{am} $. Then,  I say that $x=g^{bn}, y= g^{am} $ exist and are indeed a solution ("you can verify that..."), hence the existence. I did not really prove it in my post, but it is easy to verify that such x,y exist, commute and verify $x^m=y^n=1$ and as such are a solution.

Comment: For uniqueness,  could you please explain why is it enough that a is unique mod n and b is unique mod m?

Comment: P.s thank you in advance!